# How to make a decorator that checks if a variable exists?

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying to learn how to make my own decorators.  I don't understand how to "call" the data inside the function that is being wrapped.

I am trying to make a really simple decorator that writes out the value of msg to a textfile.

```
def logging(f):  
    def decorator(args, **kwargs):    
        debug_file = "/tmp/easylog.txt"
        fh = open(debug_file, 'a')
        fh.write(f.message + "\n")
        fh.close() 
    return decorator  

@logging
def test(a,b):
    c=a+b
    message = "hello test"
    return c


test(4,5)
```

So the part I don't understand how to do is check for message inside the decorator.

In all the basic tutorials I've read it shows how to just take the entire return value and print it in bold or something, i'm trying to learn how to take individual values and manipulate them.

Comment: Also, I understand Python has built in logging mechanisms, but I'd like to figure out this example for the sake of learning.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code example it's not possible for your decorator code to access the value of *message*.  Remember that a decorator is a wrapper around calls to your function.  In your code *message* is defined inside of the *test()* function's scope.

You could have a global variable named message ... declared as *global* at within your function ... but that is very messy and generally considered to be poor design.

You could restructure this code so that *test()* is a method of some class; and *message* is an instance attributed (or a class attribute, if you want to be be sort of like a "global" for all instances of that class).  It would then be referred to as *self.message* (conventionally using *self*).

You could also change *test()* to return a tuple (of *(message, c)*) and then modify your decorated to extract the message and return the rest:  `msg, result = f(*args, **kwargs)` where you use *msg* as your message and return *result*.

Just remember that decorators are wrappers and you can drill into the scope of functions you're calling.